# how to insert multiple values using entity framework..?

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

I'm using Silverlight5 with MVVM framework and Entity framework. In my project i have one doubt..

I have an entity named 'Customer' the structure is as follows..

```
Customer ocustomer = new Customer(); 
ocustomer.CustomerName = customername; 
ocustomer.CompanyName = company; 
ocustomer.AddressLine1 = address1; 
ocustomer.AddressLine2 = address2; 
ocustomer.City = city; 
ocustomer.State = state; 
ocustomer.Country = country; 
ocustomer.ZipCode = zipcode; 
ocustomer.Notes = note; 

_context.Customers.Add(ocustomer);
```

Now my need is to insert the Customer value into another table Named Customer_Entity

```
     Customer_Entity ocustomerEntity=new Customer_Entity ();
     ocustomerEntity.CustomerID=Customer_ID;
     ocustomerEntity.EntityTypeID =1;
     .
     .
     .
     .
     ocustomerEntity.CreatedTime =System.DateTime.Now;
     ocustomerEntity.CreatedBy=Common.ActiveData.Instance.userid;
```

Here my need is to insert the customer value to Customer_Entity in every single row..
Customer_Entity Table Structure is as follows,

```
EntityID| CustomerID| EntityValue|
----------------------------------                                                                                                 
1       | 22        |jasper      |                                                                                  
2       | 22        |Company:Raj |
3       | 22        |Address     |

ocustomer.CustomerName=customername
.
.
.
ocustomer.CreatedTime=system.DateTime.Now..
```

so i need to insert all the values in every single row using unique CustomerID..
Need help to solve this one..

Comment: The problem is, I think, your model. How do you modeled that? Do you used FLUEN API?

Comment: No Fluen API.. I'm using Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `CustomerEntity` object you should have a navigation property pointing to the corresponding `Customer` record. Similarly, I would expect that your `Customer` class has a collection of `CustomerEntity` on it as well.

In which case, you should instantiate the `Customer` object, populating with the necessary information. Don't add it to the DbSet yet, though. Afterwards, create all of the `CustomerEntity` records that you need to, connecting it to the `Customer` object by using the navigation property itself (i.e. *NOT* the ID field), and adding that `CustomerEntity` record to the corresponding DbSet in you Context class.

As a final step add your `Customer` object to the corresponding DbSet, and run SaveChanges. You should be good to go. Entity Framework should automatically generate the ID for you and populate it to the CustomerEntity records.